# How to revert to Windows 8.1 single Language from 8.1 Pro?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a Lenovo PC with Windows 8.1 Single Language(EM) version installed.

I took it to a shop to install 8.1 Pro but the key they used is blocked.

How do I revert back to windows 8.1 Single language? since upgrading from 8.1 Single language to Pro costs $119 but to activate this blocked key it costs $289.

Comment: Do you have backup/recovery disks?

Comment: no I don't have